# Error on parsing nested JSON objects in an array using Java

Tags: java, json, eclipse, parsing

I am getting an error `JSONObject["results"] not found` when trying to parse the below json string:

```
{
    "serviceModel": {
        "results": [
            {
                "application": {
                    "applicationId": 1234"applicationStatus": "Determined""applicationSubmittedDate": "2013-09-19 12:00:00 AM""applicationType": "Initial""asOfDate": "2018-12-28 02:42:26 AM""logicalApplicationId": "1234"
                }"contact": {
                    "addresses": [
                        {
                            "city": "Bridgeport""county": "Fairfield""line1": "123 Main Road""state": "CT""type": "H""zipCode": "12345"
                        }{
                            "city": "Bridgeport""county": "Fairfield""line1": "123 Main Road""state": "CT""type": "M""zipCode": "12345"
                        }
                    ]"dob": "1900-01-01""firstName": "John""gender": "MALE""homelessIndicator": "N""lastName": "Smith""otherIds": []"personId": "11233""preferredLanguage": "E""primaryApplicantIndicator": "Y""ssn": "123456789"
                }
            }
        ]"summary": {
            "resultCount": 1
        }
    }
}
```

And below is my current code (although I have tried many different iterations):

```
JSONObject jsonResults = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
JSONArray array = jsonResults.getJSONArray("results");
for (int index=0;index<array.length();index++)
    {
JSONObject obj=array.getJSONObject(index);
if (!obj.isNull("ssn"))
    }
ssn = obj.getString("ssn");
data.addToLog("SSN"+ String.valueOf(index),ssn);
    }
       }
data.addToLog("SSN",ssn);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yes, `jsonResults` does not directly contain the attribute `"results"` but in `"serviceModel"` an JSONObject which in `"results"` contains the array.

Comment: There are a lot of errors in your JSON. Please check here for the errors: https://jsonformatter.org/

Comment: Indeed, try `jsonResults.getJsonObject("serviceModel").getJsonArray("results")` .

Comment: looks like the JSON string is invalid

Comment: Thank you Arnaud!  That cleared my error.  The variable is blank when I write it to the logs so I am troubleshooting that now so I can see what the issue is what parsing that array out.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is not in valid JSON format, as you are not using comma separators between fields. Change your json string to like below and then try.

```
{"serviceModel":{"results":[{"application":{"applicationId":1234,"applicationStatus":"Determined","applicationSubmittedDate":"2013-09-19 12:00:00 AM","applicationType":"Initial","asOfDate":"2018-12-28 02:42:26 AM","logicalApplicationId":"1234"},
"contact":{"addresses":[
  {"city":"Bridgeport","county":"Fairfield","line1":"123 Main Road","state":"CT","type":"H","zipCode":"12345"},
  {"city":"Bridgeport","county":"Fairfield","line1":"123 Main Road","state":"CT","type":"M","zipCode":"12345"}],
  "dob":"1900-01-01","firstName":"John","gender":"MALE","homelessIndicator":"N","lastName":"Smith",
  "otherIds":[],
  "personId":"11233",
  "preferredLanguage":"E",
  "primaryApplicantIndicator":"Y",
  "ssn":"123456789"
}}],"summary":{"resultCount":1}}}
```

Comment: Sorry, this output is misleading, as it is from the logs and the logs don't show commas.  The actual response does have commas delimiting the objects.  Do you see an issue with the code itself?  I am doing this successfully against another BOS but that one is just returning json objects (no array).  I am using the same code.

Answer (score 0):

your json string is not well formatted, missing some comma and quote,
can use this one :

```
{"serviceModel":{"results":[{"application":{"applicationId":"1234","applicationStatus":"Determined","applicationSubmittedDate":"2013-09-19 12:00:00 AM","applicationType":"Initial","asOfDate":"2018-12-28 02:42:26 AM","logicalApplicationId":"1234"},"contact":{"addresses":[{"city":"Bridgeport","county":"Fairfield","line1":"123 Main Road","state":"CT","type":"H","zipCode":"12345"},{"city":"Bridgeport","county":"Fairfield","line1":"123 Main Road","state":"CT","type":"M","zipCode":"12345"}],"dob":"1900-01-01","firstName":"John","gender":"MALE","homelessIndicator":"N","lastName":"Smith","otherIds":[],"personId":"11233","preferredLanguage":"E","primaryApplicantIndicator":"Y","ssn":"123456789"}}],"summary":{"resultCount":1}}}
```

to get json array results can do :

```
JSONArray array = jsonResults.getJsonObject("serviceModel").getJsonArray("results");
```